# What's the policy for job advertising on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs, site-ads

I recently saw an advertisement to work at the [National Security Agency](https://www.nsa.gov/). These are pretty common (I see them on Facebook and Instagram as well), but since the NSA is not a stranger to controversy I was wondering whether there was any discretion applied to who can and cannot advertise on Stack Overflow.

For example, there have been movements for companies such as [Palantir](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies/palantir) to [divest](https://www.washingtonpost.com/business/2019/08/22/war-inside-palantir-data-mining-firms-ties-ice-under-attack-by-employees/) from the [Department of Homeland Security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Department_of_Homeland_Security) contracts related to immigration enforcement, and I was wondering if there was any similar consideration given to the ads on Stack Overflow if, say, that same department wanted to advertise here. Or perhaps if there should be some amount of consideration given to community sentiments surrounding particular companies and recruiters?

Comment: The NSA has been advertising on Stack Overflow since, well, [time immemorial](https://twitter.com/MakotoTheKnight/status/534899392507944960).

Comment: I would also ban most mega corporation (FAAMG etc.)

Comment: I should be thrilled if toxic organisations such as this could be removed from the platform. However, there is not a singular view on the morality of the military-industrial complex, and for every SO user glad to see the back of them, there would be another who believes they are a net positive contributor to the security of a nation.